# Getting animation element from storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this storyboard in resource dictionary file:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="InfoDissolve">
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" x:Name="OutVisibility" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimation                
          Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
          BeginTime="0:0:0" From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
    <DoubleAnimation              
          x:Name="OutOpacity"
          Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"            
           BeginTime="0:0:3" From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:2"/>
</Storyboard>
```

And in the code behind I get it like this

```
var sb = (Storyboard) MW.FindResource("InfoDissolve");
```

In the code behind, I need to access the outvisibility keyframe and the outopacity doubleanimation so i can change their keytime and begintime.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
sb.Children
```

This timeline collection will contain the two DoubleAnimation objects. Just add a test on their name, and do what you want with each one (you will need to cast them I believe)

Comment: Yes, i know about children but i don't know how to extract those elements i want from them.

Comment: Just do a simple foreach on it like so :             foreach (DoubleAnimation animation in sb.Children)
            {
                // Your code here
            }

Comment: Isn't there some better method than foreach? For example something like sb.Children.getChildByName("OutOpacity"). Also if i do it they way you suggested visual studio alerts me to possible invalidcastexception.